# how to access data base in framework7/cordova?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, html-framework-7

I want to use framework7 cordova to write an app, but at the same time, I want to store some data with data base, is that possible?

I have heard about the cordova-sqlite-storage plugin, does it use the window.localStorage? Is there a better solution?

Comment: This plugin is great: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sqlite-storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cordova-sqlite plugin is a good choice. Much simpler to develop and test than using file for example. With this plugin, in  intel XDK, you can test in the emulator directly.